# Getting Extra characters at the end when Creating std::string from char*

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I have just started learning C++. Now i am learning about arrays. So i am trying out different examples. One such example is given below:

```
int main()
{
    const char *ptr1 = "Anya";
    char arr[] = {'A','n','y','a'};
    
    std::string name1(ptr1); //this works 
    std::cout << name1 << std::endl;
    
    std::string name2(arr); 
    std::cout << name2 << std::endl; //this prints extra characters at the end?
    return 0;
}
```

In the above example at the last `cout` statement i am getting some extra characters at the end. My question is that how can i prevent this from happening in the above code and what is wrong with the code so that i don't make the same mistake in future?

Comment: `char arr[] = {'A','n','y','a'};` is not null terminated so you will read it out of bounds when creating the string which in turn makes your program have undefined behavior. This would work though: `char arr[] = {'A','n','y','a','\0'};`

Comment: You have Undefined behavior in your program due to non null terminated array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **problem** is that you're constructing a `std::string` using a **non null terminated array** as explained below.

When you wrote:

```
char arr[] = {'A','n','y','a'}; //not null terminated
```

The above statement creates an array that is **not null terminated**.

Next when you wrote:

```
std::string name2(arr); //undefined behavior
```

There are 2 important things to note about the above statement:

1. `arr` **decays** to a `char*` due to **type decay**.
2. This `char*` is passed as an argument to a [`std::string` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that have a parameter of type `const char*`. Essentially the above statement creates a `std::string` object from a **non null terminated** array.

But note that whenever we create a `std::string` using a `const char*`, the array to which the pointer points **must be** null terminated. Otherwise the result is **undefined behavior**.

> Undefined behavior means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

For example [here](https://onlinegdb.com/Oi_h9KsCS) the program gives expected output but [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BJ9ICGcjqv1DdYAt) it doesn't. So as i said, don't rely on the output of a program that have UB.

##### Solution

You can **solve** this by making your array null terminated as shown below.

```
char arr[] = {'A','n','y','a','\0'}; //arr is null terminated
// char arr[] = "Anya";              //this is also null terminated
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>

Comment: Another solution is to give the size when creating the `std::string` object: `std::string str(arr, 4);`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes i was thinking of mentioning that solution also and was sure that someone would point that out(like you did) but then i decided not to mention that solution because this involves counting the characters and passing that count explicitly.

Comment: `sizeof arr` is a constant expression though

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes nice!

Answer (score 4):

`char arr[] = {'A','n','y','a'};` is not null terminated so you will read it out of bounds when creating the string which in turn makes your program have *undefined behavior* (and could therefore do anything).

Either make it null terminated:

```
char arr[] = {'A','n','y','a','\0'};
```

Or, create the string from iterators:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main() {
    char arr[] = {'A', 'n', 'y', 'a'};

    std::string name2(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
    std::cout << name2 << '\n';   // now prints "Anya"
}
```

Or create it with the constructor taking the length as an argument:

```
    std::string name2(arr, sizeof arr); // `sizeof arr` is here 4
```

Comment: Or, create the string with an explicit length: `std::string str(arr, 4);`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Indeed. I added that option too.